# Variable and jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, variables

I've been trying to figure this one out for about 2 days and cant understand why this isn't working.

Say for example I declare a variable "ul" and want to say var + li display red.

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    var menu = $("ul");
    $(menu + " li").css("color", "red");
});
```

All list items should now be red. What am I doing wrong?

Example: http://jsbin.com/izela

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To change all the direct children to red you can use

```
menu.children('li').css("color","red");
```

If you require all li's within the ul (nested ul>li>ul>li) then use .find

```
menu.find('li').css("color","red");
```

Comment: I want to use what I have above, I just made the example easy to understand.

Comment: You trying to append a string to a jQuery object. It wont work!

Comment: $("ul") is a jquery object - you can not "add" a string to it and get anything useful... You can do $("li", menu) or menu.children() or menu.find().  Or you could store var menuSlector = "ul" then $(menuSelector + " li") would work, but one of the options above would be much better.

Answer (score 3):

You should run something like this:

```
menu.children('li').css('color', 'red');
```

The problem is that `menu` is an object and adding string to an object return `NaN` (in FF) which cannot be used as a selector.

Comment: How can I debug in FF to get NaN?

Comment: Well, I just run `{} + 'a'` in Firebug

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing wrong is adding a jQuery object with a string.  Try:

```
var menu = $('ul');
menu.find('li').css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
menu.children('li').css('color', 'red');
```